# How to receive tomcat critical alarms

Tags: apache, tomcat, liferay, liferay-6

As a recovery mechanism I need to write a software if my tomcat fails, I need to send email notification. Are there any api's supported from tomcat where I can receive critical events.

Any help on this regard would be very useful to me.

thanks
Lokesh

Answer (score 1):

It depends: What do you consider a critical event?

- Answering time above 2 sec/page?
- Out of Memory
- crash
- database not available
- ...

You should look for generic monitoring tools, nagios is a good starting point and there are lots of equally good alternatives, open source as well as commercial.

Then monitor your tomcat installation, e.g. through standard http, on jmx, on process/OS level. Include your infrastructure: Database, Apache, others.